Summing numpy array with an empty array
I need to sum a normal numpy array with an empty array
x = np.ones([2,3])
x + np.array([]).reshape(2,-1)

Output:
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,3) (2,0) 

Reshaping them to other dimensions does not work, e.g. x.reshape(-1) + np.array([]).
And making an if-statement to see if the right hand side term is empty or not seems not necessary.

This sounds like an XY problem. Why do you want to add them?

It seems I did have an XY problem. I wanted to mask out an array, which may or may not result in an empty array. I eventually solved the problem by turning every False element into 0. But this question intrigues me too. It seems intuitive that summing with an empty array should just return the same array, but it's an error

What you are calling an 'empty array' is not the same as an 'empty list'.  Your intuitions about it are wrong. numpy addition is done element by element.  That requires matching shapes (by broadcasting rules).

Numpy aligns on the trailing dimensions. The only "mismatch" in dimension that is allowed for broadcasting is 1 with something else.
Therefore, you could sum the two arrays if you reshape as (0, 2, 3) (or (0, 1, 1)):
x = np.ones([2,3])
x + np.array([]).reshape(-1,2,3)

# or
x + np.array([]).reshape(-1,1,1)

# or
x + np.array([])[:, None, None]

But this would result in an empty array with shape (0, 2, 3):
array([], shape=(0, 2, 3), dtype=float64)

Likewise:
x[..., None] + np.array([])
# array([], shape=(2, 3, 0), dtype=float64)

